# Postfix bounce notifications not going to email address in main.cf

Tags: postfix

I am trying to configure **Postfix** to send bounce notifications to a specific mailbox so that in my email client, **Mailwizz**, the "Bounce Server", which is configured to look to a specific mailbox, will be able to include bounces in its Campaign Log.

What I have found is that Postfix is returning bounce notifications to the reply-to email that is set in the Mailwizz campaigns. But the reply-to is not always the same and I can only set up the Mailwizz "Bounce Server" for that particular "Delivery Server" to a single mailbox.

I am new to Linux and Postfix but I have read a number of articles and tutorials that I've found on the Internet.

I have entered the lines into main.cf.

```
bounce_notice_recipient = bounce@mlr3.powersend.net

notify_classes = bounce, resource, software
```

And yes, I restarted Postfix.

I created the mailbox `bounce@mlr3.powersend.net` using **Virtualmin**. I can send and receive emails to that address with Outlook, so I know that it works.

But I am **not** receiving any bounce notifications to that mailbox.

I also use Amazon SES as a delivery server in Mailwizz, but it is set up via Web API so bounce processing is automatic.

This is the first time i have tried setting up an SMTP server. I will include `Main.cf` below. I have not had time to learn ALL the commands and configs for Postfix. Feel free to point me to documentation I may have missed for this particular application.

=====================================

Well I cannot seem to paste the contents of `main.cf` here. Even when I click the PRE code tag above it comes out almost unreadable.

I hope I have given you enough detail to point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: What's in your mail log?

Comment: @Michael Hampton...thanks for asking about the mail.log. I looked there and saw numerous entries. It concerned me because this is just a test server with very little activity, yet I saw entries of robots trying to log into the SMTP server.  I must look at ways to properly secure it from non-conforming request IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Update: As of this morning it appears that my configuration changes actually worked. I now see a bounce recorded in Mailwizz for the non-existent email address I used to test the bounce processing. Furthermore the address in question was properly blacklisted by the system.

I had thought that bounce notification had failed because the Cron job that processes Bounces had run 3 times after the Send had completed and nothing was recorded. My guess is that the address was tried several times before the bounce notification went out and I simply did not wait long enough for that response.

I apologize for any confusion my post may have caused. I hope this answer clears things up. Thank you.